# Wordpress Widget Image Too Small

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, image

I have an issue with an updated widget on Wordpress. I have a sidebar Widget using Gabfire's Widget Pack which is running version: 1.4.4, Wordpress: 4.1.1 and Theme Patterns which is also up to date.

The issue: The sidebar is loading a timthumb at 32x32 pixels. This is then being re-sized to 90x90 which results in the image looking very pixelated.

I have searched the code and it feels like I need to change the call to get a thumbnail to a larger image. Below is the code:

```
function gab_custom_query() {
    $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'gab_custom_query', 'description' => 'Query custom entries' );
    $control_ops = array( 'width' => 520, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'gab_custom_query' );
    $this->WP_Widget( 'gab_custom_query', 'Gabfire: Custom Content Query', $widget_ops, $control_ops);
}

  public function widget($args, $instance) {      
    extract( $args );
    $title    = $instance['title'];
    $swap = $instance['swap'] ? '1' : '0';
    $video = $instance['video'] ? '1' : '0';
    $c_image = $instance['c_image'];
    $c_link = $instance['c_link'];
    $postnr    = $instance['postnr'];
    $postids    = $instance['postids'];
    $cat_or_postpage    = $instance['cat_or_postpage'];
    $post_order    = $instance['post_order'];
    $d_thumb    = $instance['d_thumb'] ? '1' : '0';
    $postmeta    = $instance['postmeta'] ? '1' : '0';
    $media_w    = $instance['media_w'];
    $media_h    = $instance['media_h'];
    $excerpt_l    = $instance['excerpt_l'];
    $thumbalign    = $instance['thumbalign'];
    $postcls    = $instance['postcls'];
    $titlecls    = $instance['titlecls'];
```

Here is a print screen of the issue:

[image: Image of Low Quality Thumbnails]

As you can see, the image quality is poor. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: It seems WordPress specific issue and should be moved to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

In your shared code there are media_w and media_h variables so i think there may be a widget options to configure the size of these images.
Have  you checked the image options?

If you can could you please share the URL of your site where this widget is displaying so that i can troubleshoot it.

Comment: http://creativescreenwriting.com/nobody-knows-anything-william-goldman/ .. Scroll down, on the right hand side. I will move it now, did not know there was a wordpress for stackexchange!